# What value does a pointer to pointer get assigned when points to a dynamically allocated memory?

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation, pointer-to-pointer, pointer-to-array

Consider the following case:

```
int **my_array = new int*[10];
```

1. What do we assign to my_array here?
2. `my_array` is a pointer that points to what?
3. Is there any way to iterate through my_array (the pointer) and set up a two-dimensional array of integers (and not int*)?

Comment: Removed `dynamic-arrays` tag: tag explicitly states that is is about data structures where elements can be added  or removed without explicity memory allocation.

Comment: Thanks for the edit :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We assign to `my_array` the address of an array. The array contains pointers which can point to other arrays, but don't yet.

Yes, we can do this:

```
int **my_array = new int*[10];

for(int i=0; i<10; ++i)
  my_array[i] = new int[13];

my_array[2][11] = 500;
```

Comment: How to deallocate all the dynamically allocated memory?

Comment: This code leaks if any but the first of the `new[]` expressions throw an exception (hence downvote until fixed). To fix this, use `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` instead.

Comment: @user5241471: First iterate, calling `delete[] my_array[i];`. Then `delete[] my_array`.

Comment: In opposite direction, why?

Comment: @elyse: Point taken, but I don't want to throw exception handling (no pun intended) at a beginner who's still struggling with arrays.

Comment: @user5241471: Try it with pencil and paper, and you'll see.

Comment: When you answer people's questions, you're supposed to *help* them, not just make things worse.

Comment: And this is making things tremendously worse. You're being lazy by not even addressing the problem. Which *you* have to address because you didn't re-use somebody else's solution. This code has crippling safety problems and should never be used by anybody, least of all a beginner who could never hope to address them competently.

Comment: @Beta why throw `new[]` at them instead of `std::vector`, then? `new[]` is not for beginners, and almost never used by good experienced C++ programmers.

Comment: @elyse: Do I really have to point out that the question was about `new[]`? I know that some people prefer to teach beginners about the standard containers *instead of* dynamic structures; I prefer to teach them about dynamic structures *before* the standard containers (in the same way I'd prefer to teach someone about fire before the internal combustion engine).

Comment: @Beta: Except the ICE comes pre-packaged so they don't need to do anything to make it work safely, and all they can do with fire is set themselves on fire.

Answer (score 1):

> What do we assign to `my_array` here?

You can assign an `int*` to the elements of `my_array`. E.g.

```
my_array[0] = new int[20];
```

or

```
int i;
my_array[0] = &i;
```

> `my_array` is a pointer that points to what?

It points to an an array of 10 `int*` objects.

> Is there any way to iterate through `my_array` (the pointer) and set up a two-dimensional array of integers (and not int*)?

Not sure what you are expecting to see here. An element of `my_array` can only be an `int*`.

If you want `my_array` to be a pointer to a 2D array, you may use:

```
int (*my_array)[20] = new int[10][20];
```

Now you can use `my_array[0][0]` through `my_array[9][19]`.

**PS** If this is your attempt to understand pointers and arrays, it's all good. If you are trying to deploy this code in a working program, don't use raw arrays any more. Use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

For a 1D array, use:

```
// A 1D array with 10 elements.
std::vector<int> arr1(10);
```

For a 2D array, use:

```
// A 2D array with 10x20 elements.
std::vector<std::vector<int>> arr2(10, std::vector<int>(20));
```

Comment: I am not introduced to std::vector yet. Thanks for the answer.